# Semi colon seperated csv in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a csv as semi colon seperated, but the file output of csv has a blank line at top.
Please help me what needs to update in my below code

```
Sub WriteToCSV()
Dim FileNumber As Long
Dim temp As String
Dim cl As Range
Dim rw As Range
    FileNumber = FreeFile    '
    'get a new file number
    FileNumber = FreeFile
    ' change path & file name as required
    Open "C:\Users\standard\Desktop\automation\ankur.csv" For Output As #FileNumber
    Print #FileNumber, temp

   'change the worksheet index by its real position or Name between quotes, eg Worksheets("Sheet1").
    For Each rw In Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows
        For Each cl In rw.Cells
            temp = temp & cl.Value & ";"
        Next cl
        Print #FileNumber, temp
        're=initialise string
        temp = ""
    Next rw
    Close #FileNumber
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has `Print #FileNumber, temp` immediately after opening the file for output. As `temp` has not been set to anything, it is an empty string, hence the blank line.

Also, you don't need to use `FreeFile` twice.

Regards,